# Flatpak Android Studio cannot access /usr/lib/jvm even after permission was given

Tags: android-studio, flatpak

I have installed Android Studio as a **flatpak** and I want to set **OpenJDK 11** to run unit tests (because I am using robolectric which needs Java 9+).

From what I understand, the `/usr` directory is blacklisted, so I enabled access to `usr/lib/jvm` using the app *FlatSeal*.

When I attempt to run unit tests I get this error:
*'usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64' is not a valid JRE home*

I am pretty sure that the directory *is* a valid JRE home because using the Android Studio snap, it's recognized and tests do run.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but I just had the same problem and didn't find a solution anywhere. I finally pieced together that after enabling access `/usr/lib/jvm` it can be **found from inside the flatpak application** at the location `/var/run/host/usr/lib/jvm`.

Enabling access to /usr/lib/jvm can also be done via the command line using

`sudo flatpak override --filesystem=/usr/lib/jvm`

to enable for all flatpak applications or

`sudo flatpak override <package identifier> --filesystem=/usr/lib/jvm`

to enable for the given package.

This will still **not work** if the host java version is dynamically linked (which it will be in most cases) and the libc version of the host differs from the one in the flatpak application. In this case your only option is to use a statically linked version of java or figure out a clever linker trick that will link the host java executeable to the host libc when used from within the flatpak application.

## Alternative

You can install OpenJDK in flatpak which will be available at `/usr/lib/sdk/openjdk<version>/jvm/` from within the flatpak application.

To install OpenJDK 11 use

`flatpak install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk11`

This can not be done as the root user, so don't use sudo. Adjust the version number as needed. You will need to **restart Android Studio / IntelliJ / ...** in order to be able to access the new OpenJDK installation.

This however will cost you additional disk space. For me it was just over half a gigabyte. Also, now you have two java versions which you will both need to update seperately. Additionally, only the OpenJDK version of the jdk is avaiable for flatpak.

Comment: I have same problem, but for IntelliJ IDEA flatpak and I want it to see `/usr/lib/android-sdk`. But it's full of symlinks in the path...

Comment: It's important to note that the flatpak runtime version (e.g. 22.08, 23.08) needs to be the same on the app and SDK extension for it to be accessible within the app. Check with `flatpak info --show-sdk $your_flatpak_app_id`. The SDK can be installed on `--system` even for `--user` apps.